# Probability of two ?dependent? events

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have the following question bugging me and I'm not sure how to get to the correct answer.
It's about the probability in a video game:

A) Let's say I play 10 levels of a game, where each level has the chance to spawn a loot-box with a probability of 1%. The Prob. to get 3 loot-boxes in 10 runs would than be solved with the binomial formula P(k=3)=0.0001118478

B) Now if each box has an itempool of 12 items, what is the probability that I get exactly three of them (e.g item A, B, and C). Can I just multiply the result of the binomial formula with (1/12*1/11*1/10) or not?

Are the probabilites of both events considered dependent or independent?
And, if I would go to simulate this problem to get to P by brut-force would I choose a hidden-markov model?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: "Are the probabilites of both events considered dependent or independent?" That is ultimately up to the game coders. And technically also the intricacies of pseudo-randomness generators of computers.

Comment: If you assume that the event of which item that you receive from a specific loot-box is independent of all other considerations, then you $\color{red}{\text{almost}}$ nailed it.  You overlooked that the three items, A,B, and C can occur in any order.  So, you start with the factor of $~0.0001118478~,$ and then apply the factor of $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{12} \times \frac{1}{12} \times \frac{1}{12}.$  This specifically represents getting A from the 1st loot-box, B from the 2nd, and C from the 3rd.  Then, you apply the factor of $(3!)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: The factor of $(3!)$ represents that the acquisition of A,B, and C can be ordered in $(3!)$ ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events "get exactly 3 boxes" and "get exactly boxes with items $A, B, C$" are not independent: if the latter has happened, then the former necessarily has happened. If we call the first event $X$, and the second event $Y$, then
$$
\mathbb P(X \cap Y) = \mathbb P(Y) \neq \mathbb P(X)\mathbb P(Y).
$$
However, you don't want independence here: you are trying to calculate $\mathbb P(Y)$, which is the same as $\mathbb P(X \cap Y)$, and the calculation you were actually trying to do is as follows:
$$
\mathbb P(Y) = \mathbb P(X \cap Y) = \mathbb P(X)\mathbb P(Y \mid X).
$$
So, you start with the calculation for $X$, getting exactly three items. Then, you calculate the probability of getting exactly $A, B, C$ *under the assumption that you got three items*. You can multiply these, as you were trying to do. However, your computation for $\mathbb P(Y \mid X)$ was not quite correct: assuming that the boxes can't contain repeats, you can still get $A, B, C$ in any order, so the result is actually $3! \times \tfrac1{12} \times \tfrac1{11} \times \tfrac1{10}$. If the items in the boxes can repeat, then it's $3! \times \left(\tfrac1{12}\right)^3$.

Comment: Thank you! So in the end the overall Probability would be P(X)p(Y|X), where P(X) would be my binomial distribution and P(Y|X) would be 3!*1/12*1/11*1/10 = 5.08e-07. Could you tell me a good resource where I could learn about this?